# How to approach integration of function involving Probit and Std Norm CDF

Tags: integration, statistics

I am trying to solve the following definite integral involving some variable $x$ with a domain of $\mathbb R$.

$$\int_a^b \Phi^{-1} \big( {\Phi(x) + \Phi(2x) \over 2} \big) dx$$

$$ \text{where } a < b, a \in \mathbb R, b \in \mathbb R$$
$$\Phi^{-1} \text{ is the probit function, and } \Phi \text{ is the standard normal CDF.} $$

Is this possible to solve? I've tried searching but have not found an answer. The goal is to solve this integral in closed form (allowing $\textit{Erf}$, $\Phi$, and/or $\Phi^{-1}$ if need be).

Please let me know in the comments what other details are needed to clarify this problem. Thank you

Comment: A brute force use of *Mathematica* does not reveal a symbolic solution.  (The case where $a=-b$ which results in the integral being zero might be the only "symbolic" solution.)  Creating a list of values for $a=0$ and $b$ being a variety of values will allow you to use interpolation to get results as accurate as desired.  You'll run into numerical stability issues when $b$ gets much larger than 15 or 20 so use of multiple precision arithmetic will be required.

Comment: I would give the definition of $\Phi(x)$, but it does not have a closed form solution. The best I can provide is this...

$\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \phi(x) dx$

Where $\phi(x)$ is the standard normal PDF